# xmlBeanDefinitionStoreException while implementing spring security

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement spring security in my application> I am following this code project tutorial

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/253901/Getting-Started-Spring-Security

Here my spring-secrity.xml file looks like-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:bean="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="testadmin" password="testadminpassword"
                    authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="testuser" password="testuserpassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

But while running the code I am getting the exception-

> [2013-08-23 15:27:14,607] ERROR
>   [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization
>   failed 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 8 in XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 86;
>   cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

can any one please through the light whats the issue here and also how to rectify it, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your namespace declarations the `<beans>` element has to be prefixed with "`bean:`"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean:beans ...>
    ...
</bean:beans ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here : 
first : you have to write :

```
<beans:beans ....
</beans:beans>
```

second :

```
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

instead of

```
xmlns:bean="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```